# How to call a funtion in another function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to call other function and how to get the results of that function,

function1,

```
  exports.getprofiledatalistbyid = function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params;
  var profile= db.collection('profile');
  var requests= db.collection('requests');
  profile.find().toArray((err, result) => {
   if (err){ return console.log(err)
    }
      if(result){
                  //  console.log(result)
                   for(var i in result){
                     var id = result[i]._id;
                     var id = id.toString();
                   exports.getdetails(id)
                   }
                 }
        else{
            response = {status:'fail',data:[] };
        }
      // res.send(response);

  });
};
```

function2,

```
exports.getdetails = function (req,res) {
  // var profile= db.collection('profile');
  var requests= db.collection('requests');
  var params = req.params;
  var id = params.id;
  requests.find( { $or:[ {'sent_id':id}, {'recieved_id':id}]}).toArray((err, result) => {
   if (err){ return console.log(err)
    }
      if(result){console.log(result)
           return result;
                 }
        else{
            response = {status:'fail',data:[] };
        }

  });
};
```

routes,

```
    var profile = require('../controller/user');
 router.get('/getprofiledatalistbyid/:id?', cors(), profile.getprofiledatalistbyid);
```

So here I want to use the results of function 2 in function 1.

Can someone helps me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @klp are you still getting same error?

Comment: abdulbarik,i am trying with promise method ,hope it will work

Comment: I updated answer it may help

Comment: Thank you abdulbarik,any how i got it wrk

Answer (score 1):

> Use `module.exports` and call your `functions` by `this`

```
      module.exports = {
  getprofiledatalistbyid: function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var profile = db.collection('profile');
    var requests = db.collection('requests');
    profile.find().toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
      }
      if (result) {
        //  console.log(result)
        for (var i in result) {
          var id = result[i]._id;
          var id = id.toString();
           this.getdetails(req,res,function(err,result){
              if(!err)
            console.log(result);
           }); 
        }
      } else {
        response = {
          status: 'fail',
          data: []
        };
      }
      // res.send(response);

    });
  },

  getdetails: function(req, res,callback) {
    // var profile= db.collection('profile');
    var requests = db.collection('requests');
    var params = req.params;
    var id = params.id;
    requests.find({
      $or: [{
        'sent_id': id
      }, {
        'recieved_id': id
      }]
    }).toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err)
      }
      if (result) {
        console.log(result)
        return callback(null,result);
      } else {
        callback(null, {
          status: 'fail',
          data: []
        });
      }

    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok but how can i get the results of  this.getdetails();  function

Comment: since i am not getting anything from the lines you provided.

Comment: I updated the answer out this function where you want and use it

Comment: where should i use this module.exports = { to function1 or 2?

Comment: Where you want your function 2 result in funciton1?

Comment: where in function1?

Comment: when i do that for my function 1 the routes are unable to call the function

Comment: if(result){
                  //  console.log(result)
                   for(var i in result){
                     var id = result[i]._id;
                     var id = id.toString();
                   ---------------------exports.getdetails(id)-------------------------------
                   }

Comment: With the added  module.exports = {
  getprofiledatalistbyid: function(req, res) {
  i am not able to call these function through routes

Comment: the above 2 functions exists in the same file only

Comment: this is my error Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: Completely wrong, you can't just return a result from an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Ben,can you suggest any help

Comment: @BenFortune Thanks for point it out, I just updated my answer